# TCL logging - unwanted lines in the log file

Tags: vim, tcl

Here you can see an output of "cat tcl.log":

```
Discovered serial numbers for slot 1 olt 1:
sernoID   Vendor  Serial Number     sernoID   Vendor  Serial Number
   5      ZNTS    032902A6
```

And that's how it looks in VIM:

```
^MDiscovered serial numbers for slot 1 olt 1:
^MsernoID   Vendor  Serial Number     sernoID   Vendor  Serial Number
^M<SPACE> for next page, <CR> for next line, A for all, Q to quit^H ^H^H ^H^...
   5      ZNTS    032902A6
```

I don't mind the ^M and ^H characters, I know how to get rid of them. The problem is that for some reason my C++ program (unlike cat) is seeing the line starting with "< SPACE >". What can I do about it? I'm using the fstream library to read the log file and I want it to ignore the line I mentioned. I tried to do something like this:

```
std::ofstream logFinal("logFinal");
std::ifstream log("tcl.log");
std::string temp;
while (std::getline(log, temp)){
    if (temp.find("SPACE") != std::string::npos){
        temp = "";
    }
    logFinal << temp << std::endl;
}
```

But for some reason it doesn't find any "SPACE" in the temp variable. It looks like the "< SPACE >" is some kind of a special character of which I've never heard about.

Comment: What command do you use to open that file in Vim?

Comment: [this looks like it's related to your problem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347585.aspx) which seems to involve a lot more than just Vim and tcl.

Comment: @romainl I'm using "vim tcl.log".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're obtaining that log file from/via some sort of program that does paging. (It could be buried inside things; these things happen.) That paging program prints a message like this at the end of a page:

```
<SPACE> for next page, <CR> for next line, A for all, Q to quit
```

The `<SPACE>` is just part of some message with human-readable text; it's seven very ordinary characters. HOWEVER, the `^H` that follow it are more interesting, as they're really backspace characters; it's where the preceding characters are deleted again to make way for the next line of real output.

The easiest way (assuming you're on — or have easy access to — a Unix/Linux system) is to feed that log file through `col -b` (the `col` program with the `-b` option, to do backspace elimination). Check out this little cut-n-paste from a shell session:

```
bash$ echo -e 'abc\b\b\bdef'
def
bash$ echo -e 'abc\b\b\bdef' | od -c
0000000    a   b   c  \b  \b  \b   d   e   f  \n                        
0000012
bash$ echo -e 'abc\b\b\bdef' | col -b | od -c
0000000    d   e   f  \n                                                
0000004
```

(The `\b` should be the same as `^H` in your log file.)

Comment: That did the trick, thank you. I suspected that those "^H" characters were responsible for deleting this paging line. All I needed was a program like "col" and thank you for that. That's exactly what I was searching for. The pager program is a part of the OLT's software so I guess that it doesn't even have a name.